# Directory watcher and notifier for files added or removed

Tags: python, pyqt

I have written a piece of code that notifies if something is added or removed from a folder location:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys
import os


def xor(lst1, lst2):
    """ returns a tuple of items of item not in either of lists
    """
    x = lst2 if len(lst2) > len(lst1) else lst1
    y = lst1 if len(lst1) < len(lst2) else lst2
    return tuple(item for item in x if item not in y)


class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, pathToWatch=None, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        self._pathToWatch = pathToWatch or "/Users/ppl/Desktop/testFolder"
        self._initialContent = os.listdir(self._pathToWatch)
        self._fileSysWatcher    = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher()
        self._fileSysWatcher.addPath(self._pathToWatch)
        self.connectSignals()

    def connectSignals(self):
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self._fileSysWatcher, QtCore.SIGNAL("directoryChanged(QString)"),
            self,      QtCore.SLOT("slotDirChanged(QString)"))

    def setupUi(self):
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("Watching folder")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
        self.setWindowTitle("Detect Dir Change")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QString")   
    def slotDirChanged(self, path):
        newContent = ''.join(xor(os.listdir(path), self._initialContent))

        self._initialContent = os.listdir(path)
        msg = ""
        if newContent not in self._initialContent:
            msg = "removed: %s" % newContent
        else:
            msg = "added: %s" %  newContent
        self.label.setText("Detected Directory Change!! \n %s" % msg)


def main():  
    app         = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window      = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    window.raise_()


    return sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I have used `QFileSystemWatcher` that notifies that the change happened and then I recheck the content to compare with the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This code compares the size of the lists twice:

> ```
> x = lst2 if len(lst2) > len(lst1) else lst1
> y = lst1 if len(lst1) < len(lst2) else lst2
> ```

It would be better to do that only once:

```
longer, shorter = (lst2, lst1) if len(lst2) > len(lst1) else (lst1, lst2)
```

Notice that I also used better names instead of the meaningless x, y.

With this change the function becomes:

```
def xor(lst1, lst2):
    """ returns a tuple of items of item not in either of lists
    """
    longer, shorter = (lst2, lst1) if len(lst2) > len(lst1) else (lst1, lst2)
    return tuple(item for item in longer if item not in shorter)
```

It might also help to turn the `shorter` list into a `set` for faster lookups:

```
    longer, shorter = (lst2, set(lst1)) if len(lst2) > len(lst1) else (lst1, set(lst2))
```

However, at this point, I realize the method doesn't do what the comment says it does:
it returns the items of the longer list that are not in the shorter list,
which is not the same as items in neither lists (can be fewer than that).

---

It would be better to move `"/Users/ppl/Desktop/testFolder"` into a constant at the top of the file, rather than buried inside a class constructor.

---

It's recommended to follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python coding style guide.

For example there are several coding style violations here:

> ```
> def main():  
>     app         = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
>     window      = MyMainWindow()
>     window.show()
>     window.raise_()
>
>
>     return sys.exit(app.exec_())
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   main()
> ```

The recommended writing style would be:

```
def main():  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    window.raise_()

    return sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: in first case either can be longer or shorter, but yea having a meaning full name would makes sense.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. After that statement is executed, the longer list will be stored in `longer`, and the shorter in `shorter`.

Comment: Also, I think I noticed a bug I haven't seen before. See my update (in the first point).